# Animations to Unity3d

Tags: animation, unity, nla-editor

I'm developing a videogame, so I started creating my assets on blender. I have made a human with a walk and idle animations (Everything fine here :) ). For unity can detect that the main character's walking animation I need to apply a path to it. So I added a path as a constraint and everthing is OK, BUT also my idle animation starts moving according to this path...

There is a way that I can apply ONLY the path to the walking animation and not to the idle one?

Ty!!

Comment: what do you mean? Is the idle automatically following the path inside unity?

Comment: Yes, it applies the path to all animations

Comment: you would need to code it in unity using tansform.position

Comment: I thought the same, but is more convenient to have a path for every animation (eg for cutscenes)